# what is the usage of new keyword while using java configuration in spring

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

I have a question around the usage of new keyword being used when using java configuration in spring. What is the need of using new keyword

Refer below mentioned example:
**Code implemented using Java Config**

```
@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {
   @Bean 
   public HelloWorld helloWorld(){
     return new HelloWorld();
  }
}
```

The above code will be equivalent to the following XML configuration

```
 <beans>
    <bean id = "helloWorld" class = "com.test.HelloWorld" />
</beans>
```

In XML config, we do not use new keyword whereas in java config we are using new keyword. can someone please explain the difference

Answer (score 2):

In the XML configuration, you explain to the system what class should be instanciated (there is a "new" but it is behind the scene) but in the Java Config you actually have to return an instance so that is why we use the 'new' keyword. 'new' simply creates an instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

The two examples shown in question are not really equivalent.

What the

```
<beans>
    <bean id="helloWorld" 
          class="com.test.HelloWorld" />
</beans>
```

really does, is it tells Spring to instantiate class `com.test.HelloWorld`, and name the resulting bean "helloWorld".

Then the java-config approach is not really doing this. Instead this follows the *factory-method* pattern, when we tell Spring, that the **return value of the method is the bean**, and the **method name is the name of that bean**.

An equivalent of that in XML would be the mentioned *factory-method* approach, which in this case would look something like this:

```
<beans>

    <bean id="helloWorldConfig"
          class="com.test.HelloWorldConfig" />

    <bean id="helloWorld" 
          factory-bean="helloWorldConfig"
          factory-method="helloWorld" />

</beans>
```

Note that there are several approaches to *factory-method*. In the above, we are assuming, the `helloWorldConfig" is the factory, and we're specifying the method on that bean. Theare are cases with static factory methods too. See [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/dependency-injection-with-factory-method) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
<beans>
    <bean id = "helloWorld" class = "com.test.HelloWorld" />
</beans>
```

This XML configurations tells Spring to "create an instance of `com.test.HelloWorld` and put it in the bean context with bean id `helloWorld`".

```
@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {

    @Bean 
    public HelloWorld helloWorld(){
        return new HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

In this Java configuration, we are returning an instance of `com.test.HelloWorld`. Because of the `@Bean` annotation, this instance is put into the bean context. As no specific bean id is given, the bean id is derived from the method `hellowWorld()` and thus becomes `helloWorld`.

As you can see, both configurations require an instance of `com.test.HelloWorld`. The XML configuration implicitly creates the instance whereas in the Java configuration you have to explicitly do it yourself.